# Changing a div after a form submission using ruby on rails and ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a from being submitted via Ajax.  After this form is submitted I want to take the new information and replace a div already on the screen.

```
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px; padding-left: 10px; border-left: 1px solid black;">
    <%= form_for [@event,@default_event_status], :remote => true, :html => {:id => 'default_event_status', :'data-update-target' => 'last_status'}  do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :event_id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :video %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :audio %>
        <%= f.submit "Report all OK", :style => "margin-top: 1px;" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Div to replace

```
<div id="last_status">
Last Status:
    <%= render "last_status" %>
</div>
```

Controller

```
def create
    @event_status = EventStatus.new(params[:event_status])
    @event_status.created_by = current_user.id
    @event_status.save
    render :partial => "events/last_status", :content_type => 'text/html' 
end
```

I got the data target idea from another post online, but I'm not sure if it even does anything.  Please give any tips or ideas thanks!

HTML Page

```
<div id="monitor" style="height: 25px;">
    <div id="last_status">
    Last Status:
        <%= render "last_status" %>
    </div>
    <%= content_for :javascript do %>
        $(document).ready(
            function() {
                setInterval(function() {
                    $("#last_status_content").load("event_statuses/load_event_status");
                }, 300000);

                $('form[data-update-target]').live('ajax:success', function(evt, data) {
                    var target = $(this).data('update-target');
                    $('#' + target).html(data);
                });
            }
        );
    <% end %>

    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px; padding-left: 10px; border-left: 1px solid black;">
        <%= form_for [@event,@default_event_status], :remote => true, :html => {:id => 'default_event_status', :'data-update-target' => 'last_status'}  do |f| %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :event_id %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :video %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :audio %>
            <%= f.submit "Report all OK", :style => "margin-top: 1px;" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>

    <span id='hide_status'><%= link_to "Hide", "#", :onclick => "document.getElementById('monitor').style.display = 'none'" %> </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you have the `last_status` `div`?  Is it part of the page where your `form` is?

Comment: Yes it is.  It is directly above the form

Comment: I added the rest of the html section as one chunk under everything else i posted already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do using javascipt events in page or with :remote => true, you can return Javascript.
Check this useful cast ;)

http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript